# How to do an exact match on multiple columns and show with the latest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to only show one occurrences of an exact match of `TempString1`, `TempString2`, and `TempString3` with the latest date. How can I do an exact match of three fields and only display the row that has the latest date?

Table

```
TempString1       TempString2    TempString3   Temp4        TempDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
A                     A2           1            1.01        01/22/2020
A                     A2           1            1.02        01/21/2020
A                     A2           1            1.03        01/20/2020
A                     A2           2            1.01        01/21/2020
A                     A2           2            1.02        01/22/2020
A                     A2           2            1.03        01/20/2020
A                     A2           3            1.01        01/20/2020
A                     A2           3            1.02        01/21/2020
A                     A2           3            1.03        01/23/2020
```

OUTPUT:

```
TempString1       TempString2    TempString3   Temp4        TempDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
A                     A2           1            1.01        01/22/2020
A                     A2           2            1.02        01/22/2020
A                     A2           3            1.03        01/23/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

The [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) is a window function that assigns a sequential integer to each row within a partition of a result set. The row number starts with one for the first row in each partition.

The following shows the syntax of the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
    ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)

SELECT TempString1
    ,TempString2
    ,TempString3
    ,Temp4
    ,TempDate
FROM (
    SELECT TempString1
        ,TempString2
        ,TempString3
        ,Temp4
        ,TempDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY TempString1
            ,TempString2
            ,TempString3
            ORDER BY TempDate DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM YourTable
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Here is the live [**Demo on db<>fiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3616baa185348d78b0d0c2014f09b32d).

```
create table YourTable(TempString1 Varchar(10), TempString2  Varchar(10), TempString3 int,  Temp4   decimal(18, 2), TempDate date)
insert into YourTable Values('A', 'A2', 1, 1.01, '01/22/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 1, 02, '01/21/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 1, 1.03, '01/20/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 2, 1.01, '01/21/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 2, 1.02, '01/22/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 2, 1.03, '01/20/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 3, 1.01, '01/20/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 3, 1.02, '01/21/2020'),
('A', 'A2', 3, 1.03, '01/23/2020')

 SELECT TempString1
        ,TempString2
        ,TempString3
        ,Temp4
        ,TempDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY TempString1
            ,TempString2
            ,TempString3            
            ORDER BY TempDate DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM YourTable
```

In below query the result of above query has been considered as table of name a

```
SELECT TempString1
    ,TempString2
    ,TempString3
    ,Temp4
    ,TempDate
FROM (
    SELECT TempString1
        ,TempString2
        ,TempString3
        ,Temp4
        ,TempDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY TempString1
            ,TempString2
            ,TempString3            
            ORDER BY TempDate DESC
            ) AS RN
    FROM YourTable
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

The result of both the query is as shown below.
[image]

Comment: Suraj,    What does the a stand for in line 18?

Comment: @NewSQLLearner I have explained by separating the query into two parts.

Comment: @NewSQLLearner If this provided the answer for you , please do consider marking it as the solution. This lets future readers know it was useful, and you gain reputation, which is really helpful for getting those early privileges (such as being able to comment on other's questions). Thanks.